# How to draw GRU cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, circuitikz, neuralnetwork

I'm writing my bachelor's thesis about Deep Learning and Neural Networks.

I'm trying to draw GRU cell using tikz picture package but without success. Does anyone know how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community. This is not a do this for me site.

Comment: Please show what you tried so far. It is much easier to help you solving your problem once you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Unfortunately, this is not a "please do this for me" site. If have a work in progress but you're stuck somewhere, post your code as a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with \documentclass, includes all relevant \usepackage commands, ends with \end{document} and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. Then explain what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 6):

A very stupid method to draw these things, but I did it just for having fun and since you didn't put any code to start with, anyways it gives you the figure you want :D !

The way this code is written is very messy, so be careful editing it :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{tyell}{HTML}{FFFBAC}
\definecolor{tgray}{HTML}{332C39}
\definecolor{tblue}{HTML}{537FE7}
\definecolor{tred}{HTML}{E90064}
\definecolor{tnavy}{HTML}{301E67}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, scale=1.25]
%The rectangle :
\filldraw[rounded corners, opacity=0.5, fill=tyell](0,0)rectangle(7,5);
\draw[rounded corners, line width=0.4mm, tgray] (0,0)rectangle(7,5);
%The connection lines and + x nodes : 
\draw[thick, tgray, ->] (-1,4.5)node[left] {$h_{(t-1)}$}--(0,4.5);
\draw[thick, tgray] (0,4.5)--(2,4.5);
\draw[thick, tgray] (2.5,4.5)--(4.5,4.5);
\draw[thick, tgray, ->] (5,4.5)--(8,4.5) node[right] {$h_{(t)}$};
\draw[thick, tgray, ->] (6.5,4.5)--(6.5,6) node[right] {$y_{(t)}$};
\node[tgray] (o1) at (2.25,4.5) {$\bigotimes$};
\node[tgray] (o2) at (4.75,4.5) {$\bigoplus$};
\draw[thick, tgray] (0.5,4.5)--(0.5,0.5);
\draw[thick, tgray] (0.5,2)--(1,2); 
\draw[thick, tgray] (1.5,2)--(2,2); 
\draw[thick, tgray, ->] (1.25,1.35)--(1.25,1.8) node[midway, left] {$r_{(t)}$};
\draw[thick, tgray, ->] (0.5,0.5)--(1.25,0.5)--(1.25,0.7);
\draw[thick, tgray, ->] (2.25,1.35)  node[above left] {$z_{(t)}$} --(2.25,4.25);
\draw[thick, tgray, ->] (2.25,-0.75) node[below] {$x_{(t)}$}--(2.25,0.7);
\draw[thick, tgray, ->] (2.5,2)--(4.5,2)--(4.5,2.25);
\draw[thick, tgray, ->] (1.25,0.5)--(2.25,0.7);
\draw[thick, tgray, ->] (2.25,0.5)--(1.25,0.7);
\node[tgray] (o3) at (1.25,2) {$\bigotimes$};
\coordinate(o) at (3,3.5);
\draw[tgray, thick] (2.25,3)--(o);
\draw[tgray, thick, ->] (o)--(4.5,3.5);
\filldraw[tgray] (o)circle(0.15) node[white, scale=0.5] {$1-$};
\draw[thick, tgray, ->] (4.75,2.85)--(4.75,3.25);
\draw[thick, tgray, ->]  (4.75,3.75)--(4.75,4.25);
\node[tgray] at (4.75,3.5) {$\bigotimes$};
\draw[thick, tgray, ->] (2.25,0.5)--(5,1)--(5,2.25);
%The small FC boxes
%Box 1
\fill[tblue] (1,0.75)rectangle(1.5,1.25); 
\node[scale=0.85] at (1.25,1) {FC};
\fill[tred] (1,1.25)rectangle(1.5,1.3);
%Box 2
\fill[tblue] (2,0.75)rectangle(2.5,1.25); 
\node[scale=0.85] at (2.25,1) {FC};
\fill[tred] (2,1.25)rectangle(2.5,1.3);
%Box 3
\fill[tblue] (4.25,2.3)rectangle(5.25,2.75);
\node[scale=0.85] at (4.75,2.525) {FC};
\fill[tnavy] (4.25,2.75)rectangle(5.25,2.8);
%GRU CELL
\node[tgray] at (6,0.25) {\textbf{GRU CELL}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result :

[image]

**Edit :**

Thanks to @quark67 for the remark, forgetting some parts of the figure may occur when you use these kind of basic approach, that's why in `TikZ` drawing professionally requires implementing more macros and defining coordinates so the drawing can be done easily !

Thanks again and have a nice day :D !

Comment: Nice answer! Add just `\draw[thick, tgray, ->] (2.25,0.5)--(5,1)--(5,2.25);` to complete.

Comment: Yeeah ! Totally forgot about it  XD